# Changing reference category in multinomial logistic regression

Tags: regression, logistic, references, multinomial-logit

I am doing a regression to find what are the association between hospital admission (yes/no) and disease severity (mild, moderate, severe) using multinomial logistic regression.

I noticed that the regression estimates differ when I fit severe vs mild (mild as the reference category) and mild vs severe (severe as the reference category). I think that's probably related to degrees of freedom and other statistics that moderate vs mild (in model 1) or moderate vs severe (in model 2) have.

My questions:

1. In this case, is it possible to obtain a consistent estimates like, when using a variable with >2 categories as a covariate (say: A, B, C), A vs C is the inverse (1/) of C vs A
2. Alternatively, is it also reasonable to swap the places? So age becomes the dependent variable and severity becomes the independent variable (note that the variables are dummy and, hypothetically in my real dataset, it is plausible although the ideal way is to use severity as the dependent variable). That way I can get the consistent estimates where mild vs severe is the inverse of severe vs mild, but I'm confused as I am combining the severity (in this case dependent variable becomes independent variable) with other covariates (which are definitely independent variables)

Thanks in advance.